# Route inncomming SMTP mail on windows 2012 server

Tags: smtp

I have two SMTP domains (subdomain1.mydomain.com, subdomain2.mydomain.com) these two have a MX record pointing to smtp.mydomain.com

I have installed Microsoft SMTP server on the server at smtp.mydomain.com

So the question is, is there a way for the ms SMTP server to route the incoming emails to different servers based on domain name?

Like subdomain1.mydomain.com will be forwarded to 192.168.1 and subdomain2.mydomain.com
will be forwarded to 192.168.1.2

this case is because I have only one public ip available and need to have two different SMTP services on port 25.

If this can not be done with MS SMTP server. Do you have any recommendation for any Linux software to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with postfix transport maps. With an ubuntu server, this could be setup in 10 minutes. Google "postfix transport map".